# How can i create login.jsp page to configure spring Security oauth login

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security-oauth2

i am creating a Spring Security OAuth based login application. in that for generate OAuth Token we have to pass Username, Password, clientid and client secret. but by using login.jsp page we can pass only Username and Password.
Please any one can suggest me how should i send these details and get OAuthToken with get success to login.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration for this can be found here [in the tutorial example](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/java/demo/AuthserverApplication.java)

And a sample login [can be found here](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/resources/templates/login.ftl)